# Given three numbers as input,return true if at least one of them is a prime number

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, primes

> Given three numbers as input, return true if at least one of them is a prime number. For solving this problem, define a function that checks whether a number is a prime or not and use that function

**MyApproach:**

I made a function that checks first whether the num is prime or not(CHECK PRIME).After checking the 3 numbers,if in that function any of the number is prime it should return true
otherwise false.

> But I am getting wrong Ans for the test case

Below is my Code:

```
public boolean anyonePrime(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{    
    boolean b1=checkPrime(num1);
    boolean b2=checkPrime(num2);
    boolean b3=checkPrime(num3);
    if((b1==true) ||(b2==true) ||(b3==true))  //@Edit
    return true;
    else 
    return false;
}    
public boolean checkPrime(int num)
{
    boolean b0=true;
    if(num==1)
        return false;  //@Edit
    else
    {
        for(int i=2; i<=num/2; i++)
        { 
            if(num % i==0)
            { 
                return false;   //@Edit
            }
        }
        return true;
    } 

    if(b0==true)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
    //write your code here
    }   
}
```

@ Edit passes all test cases
For the Input

```
Parameters          ActualOutput    Expected Output     
'169' '361' '529'   true            false
```

Comment: You have `b0=true;` followed immediately by `if(b0==true)`.

Comment: Avoid `if(b0==true)`, since it is very easy to make mistake like `if(b0=true)`. Use instead `if(b0)`. Also `if (condition) return true; else return false` can be rewritten as `return condition;`.

Comment: I think I should write b0=true in else part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that `b0=true` always.  But..

- it is also rather inefficient as you don't stop immediately if the first one is prime,
- nor do you stop immediately if there is a divisor,
- nor do you stop when you reach the square root of num
- also b3=true which should be b3==true.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have a typo in your code. You set `b0=true;` before checking `if(b0==true);`, so it will always return `true`. The simple thing to do would simply be to return `false` as soon as any check finds it is not prime, rather than setting `b0` to `false` and then continuing to do more work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public boolean anyonePrime(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{    
   return (checkPrime(num1) || checkPrime(num2) || checkPrime(num3))
}    
    public boolean checkPrime(int num)
    {
     boolean b0=true;
     if(num==1)
     b0=false;
     else
     {
      for(int i=2; i<=num/2; i++)
      { 
        if(num % i == 0)
        { 
            b0=false;
        }

      }
     } 
       if(b0==true)
       return true;
       else 
       return false;
    //write your code here

    }   
}
```

I just removed the 'b0 = true line' and tidied up some code